# HP Server Automation - agent misreporting hostname

Tags: linux, solaris, hostname, hp-server-automation, opsware

I've been using HP Server Automation for some time, but have noticed an interesting issue I'm hoping the SF community has seen / knows a workaround to.

When the management agent on Solaris or RHEL (only platforms I've noticed it on) reports the hostname of the managed server, it does not return the value of `hostname`, it returns the first *alias* to that entry in `/etc/hosts`.

Any ideas on how to get around that? Other than editing `/etc/hosts` so the alias is at the end of the line instead of the front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround for this behavior through version 7.8 is to edit `/etc/hosts` so the alias is at the end of the line.